# angular json web token x-auth-token not saved properly using intreceptor

Tags: angular, jwt

when in login to the angular app i can login but the jwt is not properly saved as x-auth-token using angular interceptor which attaches the token as a headers for every output request from the application :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hAvu.jpg

i can console log the token so im surely getting it from the backend and it is properly created on the backend

tried some methods to save to the token as x-auth-token but didnt managed to

auth-interceptor.ts:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    const authToken = this._authService.getToken();
    const authRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('x-auth-token', authToken)
    });
    return next.handle(authRequest);
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthData } from './../models/auth-data';
import { UserStatuses } from '../enums/user-statuses';
import { UserTypes } from '../enums/user-types';
import { LoginAuthData } from './../models/login-auth-data';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private isAuthenticated: boolean = false
  private token: string = ' ';
  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
    private _router: Router) { }

  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }

  getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

  createUser(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string, position: string, password: string, companyName: string, country: string, city: string, state: string, zipCode: string, address: string, vat: string, userType: UserTypes, userStatus: UserStatuses) {
    const authData: AuthData = { firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, position: position, password: password, companyName: companyName, country: country, city: city, state: state, zipCode: zipCode, address: address, vat: vat, userType: userType, userStatus: userStatus };
    this._http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup', authData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  loginUser(email: string, password: string) {
    const loginAuthData: LoginAuthData = { email: email, password: password };
    this._http.post<{ token: string }>('http://localhost:5000/api/users/login', loginAuthData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const token = response.token;
        this.token = token;
        if (token) {
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.authStatusListener.next(true);
          this._router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      })
  }

  logout() {
    this.token = null;
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit({ value, valid }): void {
    if (valid) {
      console.log(value);
      this._authService.loginUser(value.email, value.password);
    }
  }

}
```

how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
Its not an issue, You are getting the token from login api only, until it came from backend it supposed to be empty only.

Look out the assignment of token property in
auth.service.ts :

export class AuthService {
  private isAuthenticated: boolean = false
  private token: string = ' ';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
    private _router: Router) { }

  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }


  loginUser(email: string, password: string) {
    const loginAuthData: LoginAuthData = { email: email, password: password };
    this._http.post<{ token: string }>('http://localhost:5000/api/users/login', loginAuthData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const token = response.token;
        this.token = token;
        if (token) {
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.authStatusListener.next(true);
          this._router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      })
  }
```